# How to cast UInt32 to UInt8

Tags: ios, swift

I need to append a UInt32 to a NSMutableData object in swift. The problem is, I can't figure out how to access a particular byte in the int.

Here is what I have tried:

```
extension NSMutableData {

  enum Endianness {
    case LittleEndian, BigEndian
  }

  func appendUInt32(myInt: UInt32, endianness: Endianness = .LittleEndian) {
    var bytes = UInt8[]()
    for i in 0..sizeof(UInt32) {
      switch endianness {
        case .LittleEndian:
          bytes.append(UInt8(myInt >> i))
        case .BigEndian:
          bytes.append(UInt8(myInt >> (sizeof(UInt32) - 1 - i)))
      }
    }
    self.appendBytes(bytes, length:bytes.count)
  }
}
```

This throws a compiler exception that I can't cast from a UInt32 to a UInt8. Is there an easy way to simply access a byte in a UInt32?

EDIT:
Summarizing final solution from the comments:

```
extension NSMutableData {

  enum Endianness {
    case LittleEndian, BigEndian
  }

  func appendUInt32(myInt: UInt32, endianness: Endianness = .LittleEndian) {
    var bytes = UInt8[]()
    for i in 0..sizeof(UInt32) {
      switch endianness {
        case .LittleEndian:
          bytes.append(UInt8(myInt >> UInt32(i * 8) & UInt32(0xff)))
        case .BigEndian:
          bytes.append(UInt8(myInt >> UInt32((sizeof(UInt32) - 1 - i) * 8) & UInt32(0xff)))
      }
    }
    self.appendBytes(bytes, length:bytes.count)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure both operands of your `>>` operator are of the same type. I made them UInt32.

```
extension NSMutableData {

    enum Endianness {
        case LittleEndian, BigEndian
    }

    func appendUInt32(myInt: UInt32, endianness: Endianness = .LittleEndian) {
        var bytes = UInt8[]()
        for i in 0..sizeof(UInt32) {
            switch endianness {
            case .LittleEndian:
                bytes.append(UInt8(myInt >> UInt32(i)))
            case .BigEndian:
                bytes.append(UInt8(myInt >> UInt32((sizeof(UInt32) - 1 - i))))
            }
        }
        self.appendBytes(bytes, length:bytes.count)
    }
}
```

Comment: OK but why does the shift count need to be a UInt32? A Swift bug? Just consider the .LittleEndian case.

Comment: the >> operator requires that the operands be the same type. Sinc myInt was already a UInt32, I made the other operand one as well

Comment: Right, seems like a bug in Swift to me.

Comment: It's just how the language is designed. I think to ensure you know what types you're putting in and what will come out.

Comment: Well, then Swift is **poorly designed** since there is no reason for a shift operator to match the size of the item being shifted. It is just a stumbling block that is unnecessary. It is this kind of thing that is going to make adopting Swift more difficult than necessary. Perhaps file a Radar?

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of people that agree. Right now I really just see it as a small nuisance and hope they focus on the multitude of other bugs and design flaws in the language.

Comment: Hmm, so that got the code to compile, but now I am getting a runtime error when trying to do the cast to a UInt8.

EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Comment: Remember Ada--the language? It was supposed to be the language "to rule them all". In 1981, C. A. R. Hoare took advantage of his Turing Award speech to criticize Ada for being overly complex and hence unreliable. Ada failed on size and complexity. Remember Swift--the language? ...

Comment: @kgreenek is your number larger than what can fit in 8 bits?

Comment: @Zaph Ada was a bit before my time. Swift still has time and I think Apple is really valuing dev input. They've already agreed to add exception handling, private and public and fix the weird mutability of arrays. I think they'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: Here is the question in a nut shell. The UInt32 contains 4 bytes. The OP would liker to append those bytes to an `NSMutableData`, something trivially done in Objective-C. It does not matter what are in the bytes, For example I have done this to get a UTF32 code point into a `NSData`. @kgreenek is that correct?

Comment: Ah, good catch! I had to do this too: myInt >> UInt32(i) & UInt32(0xff)

Comment: The problem I see with Swift is that it has to many features, to many things that are optional. Adding is easy, removing essentially impossible.

Comment: I wouldn't say removing is impossible. Apple doesn't care if the app you made with beta 2 swift won't compile on 1.0

Comment: And to wrap this up fully, I also had a derpy bug where I wasn't multiplying the number of bits to shift by 8. I added the final working code to the original post.

Comment: Cool. Glad you figured it out.